# vue-jalali-moment filter not work correctly on v-for

Tags: vue.js

I want to have a select with jalai year format, and i use 'vue-jalali-moment' for it.

```
<template>
    <div>                                                       
        <select class="select-year" v-model="year" v-select2>
            <option v-for="year in years" :value="year">
                @{{ year | moment("jYYYY")}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import select2 from 'select2';
    export default {
        name: "Profile",      
        data(){
            return {
                year: '',
            }
        },
        mounted() {           
            $('.select-year').select2({
                width: '100%',
                minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
            });           
        },     
        computed : {
            years () {
                const year = new Date().getFullYear()
                return Array.from({length: year - 1900}, (value, index) => 1901 + index)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But i have a problem, the output is wrong:

```
<select>
    <option value="1901" data-select2-id="15">1348</option>
    <option value="1902" data-select2-id="16">1348</option>
    <option value="1903" data-select2-id="17">1348</option>
    <option value="1904" data-select2-id="18">1348</option>
    .
    .
    .
    <option value="2017" data-select2-id="131">1348</option>
    <option value="2018" data-select2-id="132">1348</option>
    <option alue="2019" data-select2-id="133">1348</option>
</select>
```

It only generate 1348 for any gregorian year.
Why is not work correctly?

Comment: Your are passing the year number, but the filter requires a Date
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/jalaali/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter requires a date, then you can create an array of dates:

```
return Array.from({length: year - 1900}, (value, index) => new Date(1901 + index, 1, 1) )
```